# youtube api displays limited playlists in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am facing troubles with my app on how to  display all the channel's playlists. It only shows five playlists and if you have more it doesn't display the others.

here is my playlist adapter

```
 private class PlaylistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private PlaylistJson playlistJson;

    public PlaylistAdapter(PlaylistJson ja) {
        this.playlistJson = ja;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return playlistJson.items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public PlaylistJson.Item getItem(int i) {
        return playlistJson.items[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(PlaylistActivity.this);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, null, false);
        ImageView img =(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_snapshot);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        PlaylistJson.Item item = playlistJson.items[i];

        Ion.with(img)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.video_holder)
                .load(item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url);
        title.setText(item.snippet.title);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ***maxResults*** parameter is 5 by default in the Youtube Data API. When you make a GET request to the API to retrieve the playlist it just fetch out the top 5 results from that particular channel. You can reproduce in some REST client or even the [Try It](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#try-it) provided by Google. I tried and got the 5 results until I set up the max value to 20. According to the documentation the *maxResults* cannot exceed 50.

Here is my API request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUGhCVGZ0ZSpe5hJHWyiLwHA&key={MY_API_KEY}&maxResults=20
```